# How to order rows by hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with hierarchical, parent-child relations and want to order it by that hierarchy. Table is:

```
id|parent|type
--------------
1 |0     |1
2 |0     |1
3 |0     |1
4 |0     |2
5 |0     |2
6 |2     |2
7 |3     |2
```

And as result I want this:

```
id|parent|type
--------------
1 |0     |1
2 |0     |1
6 |2     |2
3 |0     |1
7 |3     |2
4 |0     |2
5 |0     |2
```

So I want get something like a tree view where type 1 ordered first and type 2 at the end.

Now I'm trying to use recursion but the order is wrong:

```
with cte as
(
  select id, parent, type from tbl where id=1
  union all
  select id, parent, type,
  ROW_NUMBER()over(
   order by
         (case when t.type = 1 then 1
            when t.type = 2 then 2
    else 1000
    end) as rn
  from tbl t
  inner join cte c on c.id=t.parent
)
select * from cte
order by rn
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Connect By is your best friend if you want to make such a tree like representation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: @istovatis that really cool, but I'm using MS Sql server

Comment: Can you explain how `type = 2` should be interpreted for values such as 4 and 5? Why you put them after 6, for example, and not before? And why they have this `type` value, in the first place...

Comment: can you post your `fiddle`???

Comment: @RogerWolf I have object types(type1, type2, etc), type2(and 3) is always child of type1 but also object of type1 could have children of type1. Like folders and files.

Comment: I do not think your query will work. First of all the number of columns in the anchor and recursive parts are different. Then there is an ambiguity in the column names in the recursive part

Comment: @Gleb, so parent-child relationship is more important than `type` values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the order by [`hierarchyid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290(v=sql.105).aspx) with cte is simple, not test for recursive relations

```
DECLARE @Data table (Id int identity(1,1) primary key, Parent int, Type int)

INSERT @Data VALUES 
(0, 1),
(0, 1),
(0, 1),
(0, 2),
(0, 2),
(2, 2),
(3, 2)

SELECT * FROM @Data

;WITH level AS
(
    -- The root, build the hierarchy by /{Type}.{Id}/, where Type is important then Id
    SELECT *, -- 0 AS Level,
        '/' + CONVERT(varchar(max), Type + 0.1 * Id) + '/' AS Ordering 
    FROM @Data 
    WHERE Parent = 0
    UNION ALL
    -- Connect the parent with appending the hierarchy
    SELECT d.*, -- c.Level + 1, 
        c.Ordering + CONVERT(varchar(max), d.Type + 0.1 * d.Id) + '/' 
    FROM @Data d INNER JOIN level c ON d.Parent = c.Id
)
SELECT Id, Parent, Type FROM level 
ORDER BY CAST(Ordering as hierarchyid) -- The key part to convert data type
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2318)

Comment: this is almost what I need, thank you. But one more problem, now hierarchy is right, but objects of type3 and type4 is over objects of type1 and type2. Also type1 and type2 has smaller id then3 and type4. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Gleb Glad to have some more data to test your problem

Comment: Solved this by multiplication.  (case when v.type='typ1' then -0.1
  when v.type='type2' then -0.1
  else 0.1
  end) * r.id) + '/' . Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Can be done with the following recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS REAL) rn,
    1 level
  FROM tbl
  WHERE parent = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t2.*,
    cte.rn + (CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t2.id) AS REAL) / POWER(10, cte.level)) rn,
    cte.level + 1 level
  FROM tbl t2 INNER JOIN cte
    ON t2.parent = cte.id
)
SELECT id, parent, type
FROM cte
ORDER BY rn
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/beb88/7) with more complicated sample data (deeper hierarchies, "unordered parent-child id's")

Comment: Will fail unless the data is always that simple. For example, more than 1 nest level will break it.

Comment: Thats good but, there is one detail, id could be bigger then parent id.

Comment: @Gleb - modified answer, will work for all deeper hierarchies, "unordered parent-child id's", see fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
(
  select *, 1 level, row_number() over (order by id) rn
  from tbl
  where parent = 0
  union all
  select t.*, cte.level + 1 level, cte.rn
  from cte
  inner join tbl t on cte.id = t.parent
)
select id, parent, type from cte order by rn, level
```